# Scale factor in standard cosmology

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

In standard cosmology the density $\rho$ is given by:

$\rho=\rho_0\left(\frac{a_0}{a}\right)^{3(1+w)}$

where $w=P/\rho=$ const depends on the particle content ($P$ is the pressure). The Friedmann equation is

$\left(\frac{a'}{a}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho$,

where the prime is a cosmic time detivative and I have neglected curvature and the cosmological constant.

Now inserting the first equation into the Friedmann equation I get:

$\left(\frac{a'}{a}\right)^2\sim \left(\frac{a_0}{a}\right)^{3(1+w)}\Rightarrow a'\sim a^{-3/2(1+w)+1}$

integrating this gives

$a\sim \tau^{-3/2(1+w)+2}$

where $\tau$ is the cosmic time. However in my book ( The Cosmic Microwave Background by Ruth Durrer, page 6, equation 1.25 https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cosmic-microwave-background/10D066B56BBBA899F3B89A29E0B3B78B ) they get

$a\sim \tau^{2/3(1+w)}$

Can you spot my mistake?

Comment: If you dont show us your calculations in steps, how can we spot the error ?

Comment: I added the short calculation

Comment: Why you are not writing the things in a more nicer way..like putting paranthesis or adding that "+1" into the equation... I guess its also confusing for you.  $\dot{a}^2 = a^{-3(1+w)}a^2$ or $\dot{a} \equiv \frac{da}{d\tau} = a^{(-1-3w)/2}$. Now take the integral of this.

Comment: When you take the integral you are actually finding a function of $\tau$ in terms of $a$ (i.e, $\tau(a)$). In order to find the $a(\tau)$ you need to take the inverse of the function (i.e., the result of the integral)

Comment: Ok thank you! I got it!

Comment: your welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$da a^{3/2(1+w)-1}=d\tau\Rightarrow a=\tau^{2/(3(1+w))}$